# How to print the keys of a list with using strings ?

Tags: string, python-3.x, for-loop, printing

I want to see all the keys of these lists, yet I am having trouble printing them. Would be great if you can correct my way of thinking.

Best Regards,

Deniz

```
batch_meta = all_data[0]
data_batch1 = all_data[1]
data_batch2 = all_data[2]
data_batch3 = all_data[3]
data_batch4 = all_data[4]
data_batch5 = all_data[5]
test_batch = all_data[6]

#print(batch_meta)

#print(data_batch1.keys())

for i in range(1,7) :

    y = str(i)
    x = str('data_batch')
    z = dict(x+y)
    z.keys()
```

Comment: Hello Deniz, could you provide an example with an input and  the expected output?

Comment: Hello Newbie, yes,of course. 
When I print  data_batch1.keys() alone I see this, but I want to be able to see all the data_batch..'s . That's why I tried to put it in a for loop. (output is below). For input I don't actually know what can I provide you.
Out[8]:you
dict_keys([b'filenames', b'data', b'batch_label', b'labels'])   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manipulate strings to get the names of objects.  Why not loop over `all_data` directly?  You can even loop over a slice of `all_data` if you don't want all of it

```
for batch in all_data[1:6]:
    print(batch.keys())
```